Condition under a function is uniquely identifiable by the supremum values
Let $f(x),g(x)$ be two real-valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$ and $h(x,y)$ be a real-valued function on the plane. We can assume continuity (maybe piecewise differentiability also) of these functions. Let us define $p(y) = \sup_{ \mathbb{R}} (f(x) - h(x,y))$ and $q(y) = \sup_{\mathbb{R}} (g(x) - h(x,y))$. With these notations, my question is:
Under what condition(s) on $h(x,y)$, $p(y) = q(y)$ whenever they are finite, imply $f(x) = g(x)$ (maybe almost everywhere)?
In particular, in my research, I need the result for $h(x,y) = \frac{1}{2} ([x+y])( x+y + \{ x+ y\} -1)$, where $[x]$ is the greatest integer function and $\{x\} = x- [x]$.
I am not an analyst, so I cannot judge if it is a known or easy observation. If it is a simple or known result, any pointer for some reference would be great.

I suspect that, in general, one could have uniqueness only for f,g  within a suitable restricted class of functions.  For instance,  if  h(x,y):=xy, then  p is minus the convex conjugate of  f,  and  p=q whenever f and g  have the same convex envelope, thus in general  if p=q, f=g do not need to coincide; however   f=g provided they are both convex.

Should there be an $s$ in your $h$?

Its $y$, I have fixed the formula.

@PietroMajer,  ideally, I would be happy to assume conditions on $h(x,y)$ as long as the function I need in my research satisfies it. But some mild assumptions on $f,g$ are also OK. Although, convexity for $f,g$ would be too much to assume. Can the scope for $f,g$ be broadened for the example of $h$ in the third paragraph?

Convexity is possibly not relevant; the Legendre transform is just an analogy, and it has some change of sign wrto yours. What do you mean by "scope for f,g" ?

@PietroMajer By "scope," I meant the class these two functions belong to should be as broad as possible to accommodate a large class of functions where the results would be applicable.

I guess the broader class should be the image of the transform - I suspect these are  piecewise linear

@PietroMajer yes they are piecewise linear. Is it known/trivial for the piecewise linear functions?

I think that, in general, if $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ has bounds on the  incremental ratios  $k-1\le\frac{f(x’)-f(x) }{x’-x}\le k$ (for all $x,x’$, and for  a fixed $k\in\mathbb Z$), then  $p(y)=f(k-y)-\big({k\atop2}\big)$, so   with these bounds  $f$  can be recovered from $p$.  Still not completely clear  already the situation in the class of $f$  with  $k-2\le\frac{f(x’)-f(x) }{x’-x}\le k$ though.

@PietroMajer, can you please elaborate on the partial answer as an answer?
